# Page not found accounts/signup django allauth

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm trying to incorporate django-allauth on my project. So far so good with the installation, but when I try to access the 'accounts/signup' or 'accounts/login  page, I get auto redirect to accounts/profile with page not found

here is the error :

```
 Page not found (404)
> Request Method:   GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile/
Using the URLconf defined in dari.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^accounts/ ^ ^signup/$ [name='account_signup']
^accounts/ ^ ^login/$ [name='account_login']
^accounts/ ^ ^logout/$ [name='account_logout']
^accounts/ ^ ^password/change/$ [name='account_change_password']
^accounts/ ^ ^password/set/$ [name='account_set_password']
^accounts/ ^ ^inactive/$ [name='account_inactive']
^accounts/ ^ ^email/$ [name='account_email']
^accounts/ ^ ^confirm-email/$ [name='account_email_verification_sent']
^accounts/ ^ ^confirm-email/(?P<key>\w+)/$ [name='account_confirm_email']
^accounts/ ^ ^password/reset/$ [name='account_reset_password']
^accounts/ ^ ^password/reset/done/$ [name='account_reset_password_done']
^accounts/ ^ ^password/reset/key/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<key>.+)/$ [name='account_reset_password_from_key']
^accounts/ ^ ^password/reset/key/done/$ [name='account_reset_password_from_key_done']
^accounts/ ^social/
^$ [name='home']
^about/$ [name='about']
^contact/$ [name='contact']
^admin/
^static\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current URL, accounts/profile/, didn't match any of these.
```

and here is my url

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    url(r'^$', 'profiles.views.home' , name='home'),
    url(r'^about/$', 'profiles.views.about' , name='about' ),
    url(r'^contact/$', 'contact.views.home' , name='contact' ),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),


]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Doc` says you need to implement the `/profile/` page or simply

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "<your url>"
```

Answer (score 4):

So the reason is you have logged in your admin profile.
Solution:
go to admin page -> logout.
now try accounts/login/. you will get the page.